# Determine if conditional formatting is applied to cell or cell range in Office-js

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Is there a method with office-js API to determine if conditional formatting has been applied to a cell or cell range? I see there is a  method to add conditional formatting but I don't see a method to check for existence of the conditional formatting.  If conditional formatting has been applied and it can be checked, can the formatting be read as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you could get it from here (the "Applies to" range)
[image]
You may get the "Apply to" range by the following code:

```
worksheetRange.conditionalFormats.getItemAt(0).getRange();
```

Here is the code sample for you to reference:

```
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const worksheetRange = sheet.getRange();
    worksheetRange.conditionalFormats.load("type");
    await context.sync();

    let cfRangePairs: { cf: Excel.ConditionalFormat; range: Excel.Range }[] = [];
    worksheetRange.conditionalFormats.items.forEach((item) => {
      cfRangePairs.push({
        cf: item,
        range: item.getRange().load("address")
      });
    });

    await context.sync();

    if (cfRangePairs.length > 0) {
      cfRangePairs.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item.cf.type);
        console.log(item.range.address);

      });
    } else {
      console.log("No conditional formats applied.");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond